# Where is the trace file captured from Android Profiler?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Android studio 3.0 introduced new profiling tool Android Profiler. It can capture apps method calls and plot call graphs. But where is the raw trace file?

I know in the Android studio 2.x, there are raw trace file "Trace-time.trace" generated in the Method Tracing folder after capturing. It records captured class name and method name. I can use other tools to process this raw trace. I don't know where are such files in Android studio 3.0.

Comment: You mean the `.hprof` file?

Comment: @Enzokie I add more explanation on question. I want access the raw trace file recording timestamp, class name and method name etc.

Comment: Most of this sort of stuff winds up in the `captures/` directory, off of the project root directory.

Comment: @CommonsWare I still cannot find the trace files on Android studio 3.0. No traces are shown up after recording traces.

Comment: If you are using Linux, it should be located at: `/tmp/cpu_trace*.trace`